# Cleanest way to add middlewares to a single route Js Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm wondering if I'm doing thing the cleanest way. Here's my setup:

```
Files
  - app.js
  - routes.js
  - controllers
    - wallet.js
```

`routes.js`

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const wallet = require('./controllers/wallet')

router.post('/wallet/generate', wallet.generate)
router.get('/wallet/address', wallet.address)
router.get('/wallet/balance', wallet.balance)
router.post('/wallet/transfer', wallet.transfer)

module.exports = router
```

`controllers/wallet.js`

```
const generate = async (req, res) => {
  // ...
}

const address = async (req, res) => {
  // ...
}

const balance = async (req, res) => {
  // ...
}

const _transfer = async (req, res) => {
  // ...
}

const transfer = [
  // I put my subroute specific middlewares here
  handleInvalidAddress,
  handleInvalidAmount,
  handleInvalidTokenName,
  _transfer
]

module.exports = {transfer, generate, address, balance}
```

Is this an acceptable way to do it? I couldn't find any good examples of open source express apps I could model. It seems to me that declaring my small middlewares only specific to one route in the `routes.js` file would be wrong. All the logic is in the controllers folder and the middlewares are logic.

edit: `the transfer middlewares` They are unlikely to be reused anywhere else than the wallet transfer route. In real life they are bigger and shouldn't clutter the transfer route function

```
const handleInvalidAddress = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.body.address) {
    return next()
  }
  res.status(400).send('invalid address')
}

const handleInvalidAmount = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.body.amount) {
    return next()
  }
  res.status(400).send('invalid amount')
}

const handleInvalidTokenName = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.body.tokenName) {
    return next()
  }
  res.status(400).send('invalid token name')
}
```

Comment: Are these 'controllers' reusable? Should they really be declared in separate module?

Comment: @estus I wouldn't say they're reusable. They're made specifically for that one route.

Answer (score 0):

It's a good recipe to define new router like shown above. In case middleware and route handler functions aren't reused, they can be used in-place. It doesn't need to be aware of `wallet` part because it's common to all routes:

```
const router = require('express').Router()

router.post('/generate', async (req, res) => {...})
router.get('/address', async (req, res) => {...})
router.get('/balance', async (req, res) => {...})


router.use('/transfer', function handleInvalidAddress(req, res, next) {...})
router.post('/transfer', async (req, res) => {...})

module.exports = router;
```

And mount it like:

```
const walletRouter = require('./routes/wallet')        
appRouter.use('/wallet', walletRouter);
```

In case `wallet` routes need to be distributed between several modules for some reason (e.g. plugin system), it may be beneficial to use dependency injection:

```
module.exports = router => {
    router.post('/generate', async (req, res) => {...})
    router.get('/address', async (req, res) => {...})
    router.get('/balance', async (req, res) => {...})

    router.use('/transfer', function handleInvalidAddress(req, res, next) {...})
    router.post('/transfer', async (req, res) => {...})
};
```

And mount it like:

```
const walletRouter = Router();
require('./routes/wallet')(walletRouter);
appRouter.use('/wallet', walletRouter);
```

Comment: so how would you add the handleInvalidAddress middleware to the wallet transfer route using this method?

Comment: This depends on what handleInvalidAddress is and how it's supposed to work. Is it a middleware or route handler? In case it's route handler, what route should it be available at? Please update the question with https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to be more specific.

Comment: I updated the post. Since they aren't reused and they clearly belong to single /transfer route (that they use req.body suggests that they would be useless for other /transfer routes like GET, even if they existed), it may be unreasonable to keep them as separate middlewares, they could be merged into route handler.